# mysql automatically calculating the result of multiplying the values from 3 columns and inserting it to a fourth one

Tags: mysql, triggers, calculated-columns

I have created a new column and I want to insert into this the result of multiplying the values from another three columns of this same table. The goal is to automatically calculate volume for each product id by multiplying 'length' * 'width' * 'height'.

Probably this has to be achieved using triggers but my knowledge is very limited on this matter.

Can you plz help on this?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I want to thank  all of you very much for your time and your kind gesture to offer me a solution. It was really motivating for me to continue dealing with mysql in order to find the solution to this (easy for you..not for me though) problem. Since I wasn't sure of the version (I get the result that I have Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB with PHP version: 5.6.24) I followed the solution of eggyal.  And it worked! Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 0):

> Probably this has to be achieved using triggers

Bingo! (Else you can use [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html) or, since MySQL 5.7.6, [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)).

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.volume = NEW.length * NEW.width * NEW.height
```

You may want a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger too—but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm..as a BEFORE UPDATE :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 5.7.6, this can be achieved by a generated column

```
ALTER TABLE X 
  ADD COLUMN Volume DOUBLE AS length * width * height
```

This way no trigger is needed, and the column is always updated.